# ¿Desde cuándo y por qué la palabra 'cuarta' significa 'palmo'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, cuerpo-humano

Recordando 'medidas corporales', recordaba el término cuarta como tamaño desde la uña del meñique hasta la uña del pulgar, estando todos los dedos de la mano extendidos (definición *empírica*). Sin embargo, no encuentro la relación del término con su significado y haciendo la búsqueda en el mapa de diccionarios de la academia, el término cuarta viene con la acepción de *palmo* desde 1884, por lo que se deduce que se usa en el siglo XIX, pero el periodo que da el mapa de diccionarios es amplio (de 1826 a 1884). Si alguien conoce el origen de este significado para la palabra y desde cuando se usa, gracias por compartirlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente porque un [**palmo**](https://dle.rae.es/palmo) es:

> 1. m. Distancia que va desde el extremo del pulgar hasta el del meñique, estando la mano extendida y abierta.
> 2. m. Medida de longitud de unos 20 cm, **que equivalía a la cuarta parte de una vara** y estaba dividida en doce partes iguales o dedos.

y [**vara**](https://dle.rae.es/vara?):

> 6. f. Medida de longitud que se usaba en distintas regiones de España con valores diferentes, que oscilaban entre 768 y 912 mm.